# Could you tell me if this sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, conditional-constructions, british-english

Had you not wanted him to talk so much why not tell him?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say that strictly speaking your sentence is correct. But in my opinion it's hard to understand. I would seek some way out of that "Had you not" beginning, and some decision about tense and mood. For example:

- If you did not want him to talk so much, why didn't you tell him?
- If you did not want him to talk so much, why don't you tell him?
- If you had not wanted him to talk so much, why would you not have told him?
- If you had not wanted him to talk so much, why wouldn't you tell him?

(Again, just in my opinion, these also differ in complexity and are not equally easy to understand.)